# google maps api v3 determine destination lat/long given initial lat/long, distance and angle

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to determine what will be the destination lat/long if I have the initial lat/long, and distance from start point to the end point, and a slope of 98 degree with respect to the x-axis.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What a fabulous link.  The content of that link ought to be an official part of StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html has the formulas required.

I am sorry that I can't find a pre-built script.  Perhaps someeone else knows of a script that will apply those formulas for you.  However, with a bit of effort, you should be able to take those formulas and create your own script.  (It is a hassle - but the script may not be reasonably simple to write if you do decide you need to do it yourself.)